# Issues with execute dynamic query in Entity Framework Core 6.0.8

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have used EF 6.0.8 in my project

Here, you can see an example of my code

```cs
var searchCriteria = CreateSearchString<T>(model);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria))
{
    result = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria)
        ? enumerable.AsQueryable().Where(searchCriteria, model.Search.Value.ToLower())
        : enumerable.AsQueryable();
}
```

> "( it.Parent1FirstName != null && it.Parent1FirstName.ToString().ToLower().Contains("Parent1"))"

Ui request model will send a dynamic query object (column properties and value) to filter data based on they need in grid view. See below the image.

[image]

A query was applied to my enumerable data source, but it was not filtering data. See below the image.

[image]

DATABASE SOURCE

[image]

Resolved: It was my fault. The answer is in the comment.

Comment: It looks like it is filtering. Even more than you would like)

Comment: As for actual help - I would say that this question severely lacks a [mre]

Comment: I am not sure where I was creating mistake in code :(

Comment: You have the condition `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria)` twice. Remove the `if`, because otherwise the `enumerable.AsQueryable()` without filter will never be run.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It is return all database rows if "searchCriteria" not generated.

Comment: No it doesn't, because the surrounding `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria))` prevents `result` from being assigned anything if the string is null or empty.

Comment: Understood, that can be re-factor. BUT original issues still exists.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @GertArnold Ok. Thanks for the info. I will update my original question.

Comment: This question remains utterly unanswerable: the code is full of black boxes and the problem description isn't clear. Only you know what it's about. It's not helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, It was my bad.

I was comparing `.toLower()` case only for value not for properties

It's working fine now.